# Why is my colliderect() not working correctly?

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection, collision

Collision reacts to nothing, as if the platforms have shifted to the right.
I am using it for the first time, so I would like an answer with an additional explanation...

```
    def collision(self, j):
        self.player_rect = pg.Rect(self.playerx, self.playery, player_w, player_h)
        for i in range(len(self.platfsx)):
            if self.player_rect.colliderect(pg.Rect(self.platfsx[i], self.platfsy[i], platf_w, platf_h)) and self.jump == False and self.y_change >= 0:
                j = True
                print("Hsllod")
        return j
```

Full code:

```
from random import *
import pygame as pg
import time
from math import *

pg.init()

'''Можна змінювати'''
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 500, 900
DIS = pg.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pg.display.set_caption("NoName")

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)

FPS = 60

platf_h = 20    # Висота платформи
platf_w = 100   # Широта платформи
platfs_h = 120  # Відстань між платформами

player_h = 30
player_w = 25

g = .4 # Гравітація
jump_h = 16 # Висота стрибка


class Map(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.platfsx = [randint(20, WIDTH - platf_w - 20) for i in range(19)]
        self.platfsy = [HEIGHT - 30 - i*platfs_h for i in range(19)]
        self.platfsx[0] = int(WIDTH/2 - platf_w/2)
    
    def create(self):
        if len(self.platfsx) <= 20:
            self.platfsx.append(randint(20, WIDTH - platf_w - 20))
        else:
            del self.platfsx[0]
        print(self.platfsx)
        
    def platf_draw(self):
        for i in range(len(self.platfsx)):
            pg.draw.rect(DIS, WHITE, (self.platfsx[i], self.platfsy[i], platf_w, platf_h))
            
    def background(self, color):
        DIS.fill(color)
    
    
class Player(Map):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.playerx = int(WIDTH/2 - player_w/2)
        self.y_change = 0
        self.jump = False
        self.playery = HEIGHT - player_h - 30
    
    def create(self):
        pg.draw.rect(DIS, RED, [self.playerx, self.playery, player_w, player_h])
    
    def collision(self, j):
        self.player_rect = pg.Rect(self.playerx, self.playery, player_w, player_h)
        for i in range(len(self.platfsx)):
            if self.player_rect.colliderect(pg.Rect(self.platfsx[i], self.platfsy[i], platf_w, platf_h)) and self.jump == False and self.y_change >= 0:
                j = True
                print("Hsllod")
        return j
    
    def move(self):
        if self.jump:
            self.y_change = -jump_h
            self.jump = False
        self.playery += self.y_change
        self.y_change += g
        pg.time.delay(10)


def main():
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    clock.tick(FPS)
    map = Map()
    player = Player()
    run = True
    while run:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                run = False
        keys_pressed = pg.key.get_pressed()
    
        map.background(BLACK)
        map.platf_draw()
        player.create()
        player.jump = player.collision(player.jump)
        player.move()
        pg.display.update()

    
    pg.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Thank you

Comment: `j` at the moment is the value the last time through the loop. Did you want to return when you encountered a collision instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you have 2 maps. A visible one (`map = Map()`) and a completely different invisible map in the base class of `Player`. Collision detection is computed against the invisible map, resulting in seemingly random behavior.`Player` should not be derived from `Map`, but you should pass the `map` to the `collision` method of `Player`.
Additionally, please avoid using the name [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) for a variable, as this is the name of an internal function. I suggest to use the name `game_map` instead.

```py
class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.playerx = int(WIDTH/2 - player_w/2)
        self.y_change = 0
        self.jump = False
        self.playery = HEIGHT - player_h - 30
    
    def create(self):
        pg.draw.rect(DIS, RED, [self.playerx, self.playery, player_w, player_h])
    
    def collision(self, game_map, j):
        self.player_rect = pg.Rect(self.playerx, self.playery, player_w, player_h)
        for i in range(len(game_map.platfsx)):
            if self.player_rect.colliderect(pg.Rect(game_map.platfsx[i], game_map.platfsy[i], platf_w, platf_h)) and self.jump == False and self.y_change >= 0:
                j = True
                print("Hsllod")
        return j
    
    def move(self):
        if self.jump:
            self.y_change = -jump_h
            self.jump = False
        self.playery += self.y_change
        self.y_change += g
        pg.time.delay(10)
```

```py
def main():
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    clock.tick(FPS)
    game_map = Map()
    player = Player()
    run = True
    while run:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                run = False
        keys_pressed = pg.key.get_pressed()
    
        game_map.background(BLACK)
        game_map.platf_draw()
        player.create()
        player.jump = player.collision(game_map, player.jump)  #<---
        player.move()
        pg.display.update()
```